# What are the shimano rear derailleur families?

Tags: derailleur, shopping

What are the rear derailleur families, offered by Shimano? I need to replace a Shimano Acera derailleur and am trying to decide on a replacement part.

Comment: As long as you replace it with another Shimano mountain bike derailleur that was designed for the same number of gears, it will be compatible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Cross country component**

- XTR [M980] (10 speed) – Top of the range for cross-country mountain
  bikes
- Deore XT [M780] (10 speed)
- SLX [M660] (9 and 10 speed), replaced Deore LX
- Deore [M590] (9 speed) Entry level cross-country mountain bikes
- Non-series (brakeparts, cranks and pedals)

**Trekking component**

- Deore XT
- Deore LX
- Deore

**Downhill/Freeride component**

- Saint [M820] (10 speed) – Top of the range for downhill and freeride
  bikes
- Zee [M640] (10 speed)
- Hone [M600] (9 speed) – discontinued in 2008

**Recreational mountain bikes component**

- Alivio [M410 and M430] (8 and 9 speed)
- Acera [M360] (8 and 9 speed)
- Altus [M310] (8 speed)
- Tourney (6, 7, 8 speed) – Includes several different levels of
  quality, and can be found on department-store bicycles

The above list was pilfered from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shimano#Mountain_bike_groupsets).

You're probably best to go with Acera again, to ensure it's compatible. I've had one fitted to my hybrid in the last year, so they're still available.

Comment: No road or CX (or track or TT) components?!